# using the scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset on a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have tried to use `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset` on my `UITableView` so when I reach a certain place, i.e. a hidden segmented control at the top of the table, it will then decelerate to the top of the segmented control 'sticking' it to the underneath of the navigation bar.

I have the following code:

```
- (CGPoint)tableOffsetForProposedOffset:(CGPoint)proposedOffset currentOffset:(CGPoint)currentOffset {
    NSLog(@"Current:  %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(currentOffset));
    NSLog(@"Before:   %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(proposedOffset));

    if (currentOffset.y <= -10) {
        // Show segmented control
        NSLog(@"--- Show ---");
        proposedOffset.y -= 500;
    } else if (currentOffset.y >= 42) {
        // Hide segmented control
    }

    NSLog(@"Proposed: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(proposedOffset));

    return proposedOffset;
}

- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    *targetContentOffset = [self tableOffsetForProposedOffset:*targetContentOffset currentOffset:scrollView.contentOffset];

    NSLog(@"Returned: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(*targetContentOffset));
}
```

***Please note that I am only using '500' to test with***

All of my logs show the correct details, and most importantly, the 'Returned' `*targetContentOffset` it correct too. i.e. `Returned: {0, -458}`.

What can I possibly be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You mentioned the desired behavior, but it's not clear what is the current observed behavior. If you describe what is currently happening it will be easier to try to find where is the error.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% certain (as the documentation also is very reserved about that) but I think that if `*targetContentOffset` is bigger than the maximum content offset the value will be ignored.